# PHP MySQL Not Connecting and Posting

Tags: php, html

I'm probably missing something basic, so at this point, I just need a second pair of eyes. I'm constructing a simple input form on my website so that visitors can submit some information. Right now, im just calling them jobs (i just want to get it working). When I click submit, I am not seeing any information on the PHPMYadmin side, so the SQL database is obviously not being updated. My bad for not saying this the first time.

ALSO, my password is hidden, for security reasons, but it is correct.

Here is my PHP and my HTML.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","projedl8_Jason","/////");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("projedl8_quicktern", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO jobListForm (NAME, Email, JobTitle, JobDescription)
            VALUES ('JASON', '$_POST[email]','$_POST[job_title]','$_POST[job_description]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

                        mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And lastly:

```
  <form name="submitjobform" method="post" action="job_submit.php">
    <table width="450px">
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="100" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
     </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <label for="job_title">Job Title</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
     <input  type="text" name="job_title" maxlength="30" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="comments">Job Description</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <textarea  name="job_description" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" size="100"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Here is the screen shot for PHPMYADMIN

[enter link description here](http://i380.photobucket.com/albums/oo245/yoyo1299/ScreenShot2012-07-08at24139PM.png)

Comment: Why do you use `"/////"` in the third parameter of `mysql_connect()`?

Comment: What's the question? What output do you get?

Comment: I see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) fingerprints ALL OVER this code.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. As a fellow *Jason*, you're embarrassing me :) @Lion, *Jason* just doesn't want to share the password with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be the missing single quotes inside `$_POST[...]`.

However your solution is open to **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**, so better use prepared statements,
that handle quotes/backslashes, escaping in the parameters.

```
    $db = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);
    $stmt2 = $db->stmt_init();
    if (!$stmt2->prepare("INSERT INTO jobListForm (NAME, Email, JobTitle, JobDescription)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        die('Error');
    } else {
        $stmt2->bind_param('ssss', 'JASON', $_POST['email'], $_POST['job_title'], $_POST['job_description']);
        if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
            die;
        } else {
            $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        }
    }
    $stmt2->close();
```

(The four ssss indicate that every parameter is a string.)

Comment: <?php
        $db = new mysqli($localhost, $projedl8_Jason, $///, $projedl8_quicktern);
    $stmt2 = $db->stmt_init();
    if (!$stmt2->prepare("INSERT INTO jobListForm (NAME, Email, JobTitle, JobDescription)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";)) {
        die;
    } else {
        $stmt2->bind_param('ssss', 'JASON', $_POST['email'], $_POST['job_title'], $_POST['job_description']);
        if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
            die;
        } else {
            $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        }
    }
    $stmt2->close();
    ?>

Comment: hmmm, still doesn't show up in the SQL db

Comment: Now I get a "page cannot be found". Weird, i didn't change the name of the php file

Comment: `die` should be `die('Error') and `$localhost` of course `'localhost'` etc. Did you try to execute the statement in mysql, without php?

Comment: It gives me a syntax error... :/

Comment: There was a copy error, removed the semicolon after the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem is simply the "mysql won't connect" part (I also assume that '////' is the correct value for the field)

Try replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" or with the IP of the internal network interface, in case the connection is not happening through Unix sockets.

However, your code has a really bad case of SQL injection vulnerability, which is relatively harmless in this form and using MySQL (it is an INSERT form and MySQL doesn't allow multiple statements to execute, so posting

```
email=','',''); DROP TABLE jobListForm; --
```

will result in

```
INSERT INTO jobListForm (NAME, Email, JobTitle, JobDescription)
        VALUES ('JASON', '','',''); DROP TABLE jobListForm; --','','');
```

being passed to MySQL, and only the first query, the INSERT, will execute.

In other places, though, this might allow a SELECT...LOGIN query to return TRUE and the record for the administrator even if the password submitted was wrong, allowing anyone to administrate your system.

Use prepared statements with PDO, or thoroughly validate what gets shipped in your POSTs.